# Searching a record which has been put into an array of records in delphi/lazarus

Tags: arrays, delphi, record, pascal, lazarus

I have an array holding many records. Set up like this:

```
Tcustomer= record
  Name: string[40];
  Address: string[100];
  phone: string[15];
  email:string[50]; 
end;
```

Now, Lets say I wanted to search this array for a person with a certain name *and* certain address. How would I go about this? So basically searching more than just 1 element. (I can search for specifically 1 property but cant filter more than 1)

Attached is a picture of how my form is set up and this'll show in more detail as to what I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: Loop over your array looking for matches. One wonders why you use fixed length strings these days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thats my point, I can only do it in a loop when searching for 1 specific thing in my array. How are you thinking about it? :S

Comment: Ultimately there will be a loop which walks over all elements checking for a match by some criteria. If you want to find multiple matches you can do that. If you have a specific problem, tell us more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thats the only problem I have :( could you please type me up some code as an example when your free? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just iterate the array and check multiple properties of the record in your loop. Here's an example that searches for a match in either name, address, phone, or email; to change it to look for a match in multiple record properties (like name *and* address), just replace the `or` clauses in the test with two or more tests using `and` instead, as in `if (Customers[Idx].Name = Name) and (Customers[Idx].Address = Address) then`.

```
type
  TCustomer = record
    Name: string[40];
    Address: string[100];
    Phone: string[15];
    Email:string[50]; 
  end;

  TCustomerList: array of TCustomer;

function FindCustomer(const Name, Address, EMail,
  Phone: string; const Customers: TCustomerList): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;                           // Value if no match found
  for i := Low(Customers) to High(Customers) do
  begin
    if (Customers[i].Name = Name) or        // Name matches?
       (Customers[i].Address = Address) or  // Address?
       (Customers[i].EMail = EMail) or      // Same email?
       (Customers[i].Phone = Phone) then    // Same phone
      begin
        Result := i;                        // Yep. We have a match.
        Exit;                               // We're done.
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Sample use:

```
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  // Customers is your array of TCustomer in a TCustomerList
  Idx := FindCustomer('', '', '', 'jsmith@example.com', Customers);
  if (Idx = -1) then
    WriteLn('No match found.')
  else
    WriteLn(Format('Customer %d: %s %s %s %s',
                   [Idx, 
                    Customers[Idx].Name,
                    Customers[Idx].Address,
                    Customers[Idx].Phone,
                    Customers[Idx].EMail]));
end;
```

To match on a combination of values (such as `Name` and `Address`), just change the condition in the `if` appropriately:

```
function FindCustomerByNameAndAddress(const Name, Address: string; 
  const Customers: TCustomerList): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;                           // Value if no match found
  for i := Low(Customers) to High(Customers) do
  begin
    if (Customers[i].Name = Name) then          // Name matches.
      if (Customers[i].Address = Address) then  // Does address?
      begin
        Result := i;                            // Yep. We found it
        Exit;                               
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Sample use:

```
Idx := FindCustomerByNameAndAddress('John Smith', '123 Main Street`);
if Idx = -1 then
  // Not found
else
  // Found. Same code as above to access record.
```

Comment: Why not just compare records with CompareMem? Your `FindCustomer` will not return an exact match.

Comment: @user3060326: Because the poster didn't ask for an **exact** match of an entire record. The question asks about a match between two fields of the record (name and address), and there are four fields. I gave code for finding any single field (regardless of the content of the other three) and text explaining how to change it to find any combination of two or more fields. If the volume of data is high enough to worry about speed, there are better and more efficient ways to store it to improve search capabilities.

Comment: @user CompareMem cannot work here. It's also, as a general rule, usually a mistake to use it. Think about the characters in each string, that are allocated but not initialized. And think about padding and alignment.

Comment: @KenWhite thats what I want, an exact match. Sorry, I should have been more clear. This code is where I'm currently at but that's the step I need to reach. Any idea?

Comment: @user3478431: My code will give you an exact match on a name, address, email, or phone. With the changes I mention, you can do an exact match on two, three, or four fields. What the first comment is suggesting is not what you're asking about - my code (and the additional text) is exactly what you're looking for as a solution. See my edited answer.

Comment: @KenWhite your a legend! The edited answer is what I was looking for and it now works :) thanks :)